# Python docstrings only allow two indent levels

Tags: indentation, python, yasnippet

I am trying to write a docstring that follows Google's style guide such that it looks something like:

```
def testFunction(a, b):
    """
    Args:
        a (str):
        b (str):

    Returns:
        Description of return
```

I am doing this through a `yasnippet` following the [accepted answer to this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19422/library-for-automatically-inserting-python-docstring-in-google-style), and everything works except for the indentation of the "return description" because my `emacs` isn't allowing an indentation beyond the first level within the docstring using `TAB`. Using `indent` within a `lisp` function gives the correct indentation (under `Args:`), but using `TAB` within the buffer (or in the snippet) does not. As such my docstring looks like:

```
def testFunction(a, b):
    """
    Args:
        a (str):
        b (str):

    Returns:
    Description of return
```

Any ideas to overcome the general problem of not being able to force another layer of indent within the docstring using `TAB` in `python-mode`?

I've tried making a barebones `init.el` to avoid loading anything that may create this behavior but still get the same issue. I am using `emacs` version 24.5.1, in case that provides any clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue for quite a while and I couldn't figure out how to change it. It didn't affect me much during my day to day work however, so I usually fixed it manually.

I did however find a fix recently however. It is detailed here:

https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/498

Basically, I now use the `mmm-mode`-package to make all docstrings behave as they are in `rst-mode`. This may be overkill for the Google style, but you could use almost the same configuration but change the sub-mode to use e.g., `text-mode` instead.

The configuration I'm using can be seen below (using [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)):

```
(use-package mmm-mode
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :commands mmm-mode
  :init
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'mmm-mode)
  :config

  ;; Add python + rst major mode configuration.
  (defun rst-python-statement-is-docstring (begin)
    "Return true if beginning of statement is BEGIN."
    (save-excursion
      (save-match-data
        (python-nav-beginning-of-statement)
        (looking-at-p begin))))

  (defun rst-python-front-verify ()
    "Verify that we're looking at a python docstring."
    (rst-python-statement-is-docstring (match-string 0)))

  (setq mmm-parse-when-idle 't)
  (add-to-list 'mmm-save-local-variables 'adaptive-fill-regexp)
  (add-to-list 'mmm-save-local-variables 'fill-paragraph-function)

  (mmm-add-classes
   '((rst-python-docstrings
      :submode rst-mode
      :face mmm-comment-submode-face
      :front "u?\\(\"\"\"\\|\'\'\'\\)"
      :front-verify rst-python-front-verify
      :back "~1"
      :end-not-begin t
      :save-matches 1
      :insert ((?d embdocstring nil @ "u\"\"\"" @ _ @ "\"\"\"" @))
      :delimiter-mode nil)))

  (mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'python-mode nil 'rst-python-docstrings))
```

I should note that mixing major modes in this fashion is usually frowned upon (as you can read in the github thread) and it may introduce various subtle issues. Personally however, I haven't run into any issues yet.

Comment: This does indeed work, though I think I'll use the manual method instead of mixing major nodes.

Answer (score 0):

As a simpler (read: less-sophisticated) alternative to @Xaldew's nice answer, I created a keyboard binding that indents to column 8 (since that's generally where I need to be and can't get to with Google-style docstrings) with a minimum of 4 spaces inserted (for wrapped descriptions). I used `C-<tab>` since it was unused in my Python mode, but maybe choose something that works for you.

I use `elpy`, so I put it in the `use-package` block below. The relevant portion is:

```lisp
(use-package elpy
  ;; omitted
  :bind
  (("C-<tab>" . (lambda () (interactive) (indent-to-column 8 4))))
  ;; omitted
  )
```